# Scroll over the ad (iframe) blocks other interaction with the page

Tags: html, css, adsense

I have come across unexpected behaviour on pages which contain ads from Google Adsense.

On mobiles (iOS and Android / Safari / Google Chrome) **if user scroll over the ad (iframe), the browser blocks other interactions with a page**.

For example see https://streamable.com/ypasq if I scroll without touching the ad, the link works fine. But if I scroll over the ad, the link is not working. Source here https://next.plnkr.co/edit/sZq85SBgu1PVmSGH?preview

Do you have any idea how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Apparently you need to place the iframe in a wrapper with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. Read [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios).

Comment: This does not help. I figure out that `<body ontouchstart="">` can fix the problem, but I do not know how it works.